# No se me ejecuta Blade en la web

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema.
Cuando cargo una página que dentro tiene código Blade, este no se me ejecuta. Aquí les dejo el código que tengo en esa web y el nombre del archivo es medicamentos.blade.php
Tengo el servidor local montado sobre Laragon. Me estuvo funcionando bien hasta un momento, yo no modifique nada en el servidor, no se que pasó. Todo lo que está en Blade no se ejecuta.
Saludos y gracias...

```
@extends ('plantilla')

@section('title', 'Medicamentos')

@section('contenido')

    <h1>Medicamentos Disponibles</h1>
 
    <a href="{{route('medicament.create')}}">Adicionar Medicamentos</a><br><br><br>

    @include ('partials.msg')

    <table border="1">
        <tr align="center">
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Tipo</td>
            <td>Concentración</td>
        </tr>
    @forelse ($medics as $medicsItem)
        <tr>
            <td align="center">{{ $medicsItem->nombre }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ $medicsItem->tipo }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ $medicsItem->concentracion }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('medicament.show', $medicsItem) }}">Ver</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('medicament.edit', $medicsItem) }}">Editar</a></td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="{{route ('medicament.destroy', $medicsItem)}}">
                    @csrf @method('DELETE')
                    <button>Eliminar</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        @empty
            <h2>No hay medicamentos</h2>
        </tr>
    @endforelse
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: Tus archivos tienen la extension blade.php?

Comment: ¿Las pruebas las haces de forma local o en un hosting? Asegúrate que la extensión de los archivos sea la correcta (```archivo.blade.php```). (Te sugiero que detalles la mayor info que puedas, como el código que te da problemas, si estás trabajando de forma local o ya subiste tu página a algún hosting...)

Comment: Hola Anniester, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!